# Download an excel file returned from a spring MVC Controller (Ajax call)

Tags: excel, spring-mvc, download, xlsx, filesaver.js

I'm developing a web application with spring boot, spring mvc.

I have a controller method that returned an excel file as the following:

```
in = new FileInputStream(comparsionreport);
    out = response.getOutputStream();
    response.setHeader("Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=" + comparsionreport.getName());
    response.setContentType("application/vnd.ms-excel");
    response.addHeader("filename", comparsionreport.getName());
    byte[] buffer = new byte[BUFFER_SIZE]; // use bigger if you want
    int length = 0;
    while ((length = in.read(buffer)) > 0) {
        out.write(buffer, 0, length);
    }
    in.close();
    out.close();
```

In view (javascript), an AJAX call is done like the following:

```
$.ajax({
            url : $('#compareFrm').attr('action'),
            type : 'post',
            responseType: "arraybuffer",
            data : $('#compareFrm').serialize(),
            success : function(data, status, xhr) {
                // download response file
                var jsonData = JSON.stringify(data);
                var blob = new Blob(
                        [ jsonData ],
                        {
                            type: "application/vnd.ms-excel"
                        });
                saveAs(blob, xhr.getResponseHeader('filename'));
            },
            error : function(data) {
            }
            });
```

An excel file with the good name is downloaded but when open it, it says that file cannot be open because of wrong extension or format (corrupted file so...)

Anyone have any idea? it's a blocking issue for me :(

Thanks

Comment: no one has an idea? please help

Comment: suggestion: try to return only data on ajax level and on javascript - convert to excel and download it - simple.